# This community is disconnected from the workplace

Tags: support, specific-question, quality

I am finding it hard to justify recommending TWP after this.
[Telling a Coworker they aren't invited into my house](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/173302/telling-a-coworker-they-arent-invited-into-my-house)

The user has existing tensions with a co-worker, and one of the symptoms of the dysfunctional situations is needing to prevent the co-worker to attend an event organised at her/his home.

The most upvoted question is "solving the problem" by explaining how to assertively ask the co-worker to go away if she/he comes by.

Yes, this is a question for a problem which has a solution.
Yes, the answer is a potentially valid solution.
No, this doesn't solve anything. The user is going to have the same tensions in the office the day after, with more tensions arising from this new incident - and if it's not this party, it will be another event.

I think that the community is becoming disconnected by the workplace. In the workplace, solving a symptom does not solve the cause. People are people, and "questions with an answer" are spectacularly misleading, biased ways to shut down a problem without thinking hard about the big picture.

Comment: You sure you aren't just upset by the downvoting of your "you should quit" answer in response to the "How do I politely tell her that she isn't allowed in my home?" question?

Comment: The only "disconnect from the workplace" I see here is [your answer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/173305/25739) recommending the OP to literally disconnect from their workplace. That doesn't seem to address the root behavioural issue any more than your narrow interpretation of the other answers. It's also rather a stretch to extrapolate that interpretation to the entire community. And since your last sentence seems to be a sort of general indictment of the core concept of a Q&A website I must say I strongly disagree with this assessment.

Comment: Suggest renaming this question “I think my answer to a question was best but others don’t.”

Answer (score 7):

Did you offer up a better answer?

Comment: ...Or flag any low-quality content you see? Or better yet, suggest an edit?

Answer (score 4):

The answers are to the questions. Your answer is about the mental health issue (imo quitting is a good option for that).

I'm not really sure about it because over here PTSD is an extreme diagnosis usually for victims of something horrific and violent. I'm assuming it means something else in the users locale or the doctor would already have told the OP to get out of that environment as their first action, or at the very least take extended leave.

Comment: +1 for "The answers are to the questions" - besides, while we might have a few stray mental health professionals around here, the large majority of us are not qualified to give advice on how to solve PTSD